# FCM getting MismatchSenderId

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application that uses Google FCM for sending push notifications.

When i send a push notification to a group of users, i get a response of `MismatchSenderId` for some of them. Even though, all users have the exact same application. How can some of the users get a success response and others get a MismatchSenderId?

I have researched a lot and made sure I have added all prerequisites that FCM needs.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Sample response:

```
{"multicast_id":5340432438815499122,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the server side sending code (PHP):

```
$fields = array
(
  'to' => $token,
  'data' => $data
);

$headers = array
(
  'Authorization: key=AIza**************************',
  'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields) );
curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems that the issue has been resolved with the SDK updates. I am using now the latest `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1`, I don't get "MismatchSenderId" anymore.

Comment: MismatchSenderId means that your client is registering with a different server than the one you are using to send. Are all your clients registering with the same project? Also could you include the MismatchSenderId response in the question?

Comment: Yes, same project, same application, same server key.

Comment: Could you show the code of how you sent this message? I might know the cause of problem..

Comment: @AnZ i have added code to the question

Comment: @TareKhoury, thanks. First of all. Make sure that Authorization key you use is `Server Key` (could be found in firebase console in server tab) and not `API_KEY` from `google-service.json`. Second, make sure you set the destination correct. For example, `to" : "/topics/yourtopic"` if you want to send message to all devices (they should subscribe first to that topic). Or try to send to particular device, then there is needed to type device token (received up on first start in firebase service) `cec5gH04....92IyHrB2K`

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am facing the same problem!

Comment: @Merlin1896 Nope, still facing issues

Comment: I got rid of the problem but cannot really say what did the trick. I deleted my app from firebase, recreated it, removed the app from my test device so that it got a new UID from firebase and then it worked. Removing the app from firebase did not change the server key so that I did not have to change that in my script. I really dont knwo what is going on.

Comment: @TareKhoury I'm trying to perform FCM-XMPP connection on Android using **smack** lib. Any idea how to perform connection. I'm getting **org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.** after performing **XMPPTCPConnection.login()** call. Any suggestion!!

Comment: @TareKhoury I'm facing the same problem. Same application on different phones. Some work, some don't. The issue is intermittent for me.

Comment: Make sure you have updated the google-services.json file on app

Comment: I am facing this as well. I am able to send notification from firebase console but not from the FCM.

Comment: Did anyone manage to solve the problem in the past 2 years?

Comment: @TareKKhoury Did you get any solution??

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy did you get any solution?

Comment: I cant remember now sorry @kapilsingh

Answer (score 54):

Firebase has upgraded their server keys to new version.
Use new keys instead of old one.

> go to settings->project settings->cloud messaging tab

[image]

Comment: It doesn't make any difference if you are using Server key OR Legacy server key

Answer (score 30):

Just an FYI. I was running into this error, even though I *swear* the android app I was testing was built with the latest/greatest google-services.json file and I could send from the FCM console to the app.
I rebuilt the app after doing a `Clean Project` and now I can send to the app with the FCM token it registers. So, maybe try a clean rebuild before beating your head against the wall for too long.

Comment: this was the solution for me!

Comment: Both projects use the new FCM and this was still the issue. Saved my day!

Comment: This was the solution. I wish we had better error messages.

Comment: You sir, are an Angel.

Comment: You saved my week, wasted a day.

Answer (score 29):

I found this solution:

- First I check server key is correct or not it was correct which is
  like  AIzaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
- Then I check Sender Id like 79XXXXXXXX it was also correct.
- Main issue was in **device_ID(UDID)** to whom I have to send the notification. Actually DeviceId we got on android side in **FCM** is different than **GCM**. You can't use **GCM** created **DeviceId** in **FCM**.

Comment: You helped me a lot. I had to ask for the app developer to include the sender id on the code, then my FCM API KEY worked. Many thanks.

Comment: When we upgrade our backend and Android app to FCM, How can we then send a push notification to users how are already registered with GCM tokens in the backend. ?

Comment: FCM system supports old GCM tokens https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq

Comment: Hi man. Where do you place the senderId? I see I'm not using it and I have been able to send notifications some days ago. Thanks in advance mate

Comment: Hi @voghDev from backend using FCM Api (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) sending *senderId* in headers and on app side same *SenderId* is used to create UDID(device_Id)

Comment: @PinkeshDarji on app side we have thing like every-time user login into the app i update UDID of user thats how we get updated UDID(Device_Id) for old users

Comment: -First I check server key is correct or not it was correct which is like AIzaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.   That fixed my issue. Thank you very much

Comment: My keys where not inputted corrected

Answer (score 27):

**THIS WORKED FOR ME:**

- CHECK WHICH FIREBASE PROJECT YOUR CURRENT ANDROID PROJECT IS LINKED TO AND USE 
  *Server Key* FROM THAT PROJECT.

I was using Server key from a different firebase project(say Project 2). I used the same server key as linked with my android project(Say Project 1) and it worked. In my experience, using one firebase app for one entire android project seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: I faced with same situation. Old project linked to android app. And server key of new project isn't work (return error MismatchSenderId). After I remove android app in old project, new server key from new project became worked.

Comment: This is perfect, and worked for me like a charm

Answer (score 16):

In my case, I just was mistaking about project credentials: using google-services.json from one project, and server key from another.

Answer (score 11):

We spent hours and hours to resolve this issue. What we found that token was being generated using different FCM account settings (google-services.json) and notification was being set using different FCM account.
When we synced both it worked like a charm.

Comment: This happened to me too. Make 100% sure the token generated for your phone is the correct build environment (dev/alpha/prod)

Answer (score 10):

My problem was solved by entering the correct key as shown below.

Copy **Server key** like this picture
[image]

And then copy this code in post man like this picture
[image]

and Body is *row* like this picture

[image]
***NOTE:***

- You must add **key=** before Server key in header
- Make sure you enter the **header keys correctly** (Authorization =
  "key=..." and ContentType = "application/json")
- You have sent the request to the **correct address**
  (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send and Post method)

Answer (score 6):

- I cross verified all the credentials
- Added new server key and deleted old one
- Downloaded google-services.json again

Nothing solved the issue

Then I just clean the project and then rebuild the project.After that it's working fine

Comment: You save my day :D

Answer (score 5):

I found that the `senderId` is different from the project number in the FCM console
so I re-downloaded google-services.json and everything works fine

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you remove all the Parse code from your app (libraries, receivers in AndroidManifest, etc). I found that intermittently push notifications were not working. From my observations, it would work on fresh installs but not app updates from the play store.

I believe something internal to Parse was conflicting with FCM (Parse uses GCM, so I'm guessing it had to do with using GCM and FCM simultaneously). As soon as I ripped out all the Parse receivers and libraries, things worked great.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue in my react-native - node.js project.
I wanted to send notifications in android.
Everything was set-up and working fine (i.e. I was able to send notifications from node.js and receive notifications on android device).

After a few days, I had to use a different firebase account, so I changed the google-services.json file in my project's *android/app* folder and rebuilt the project. But, when I tried sending notification from my server once again, I got an error -

```
{.............
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'messaging/mismatched-credential',
    message: 'SenderId mismatch'
  },
  codePrefix: 'messaging'
}
```

**Solution:**

the XML file at the location -
***app/build/generated/res/google-services/{build_type}/values/values.xml*** was not getting automatically updated according to new *google-services.json*.
It still consisted of old values from my previous *google-services.json* file. I had to change *values.xml* file manually.

This is how *app/build/generated/res/google-services/{build_type}/values/values.xml* file look (You need to change it manually if it does not get updated automatically according to *google-services.json*)-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <! -- Present in all applications -->
    <string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">1:1035469437089:android:73a4fb8297b2cd4f</string>

    <! -- Present in applications with the appropriate services configured -->
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">1035469437089</string>
    <string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">337894902146-e4uksm38sne0bqrj6uvkbo4oiu4hvigl.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">UA-65557217-3</string>
    <string name="firebase_database_url" translatable="false">https://example-url.firebaseio.com</string>
    <string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">AIzbSyCILMsOuUKwN3qhtxrPq7FFemDJUAXTyZ8</string>
    <string name="google_crash_reporting_api_key" translatable="false">AIzbSyCILMsOuUKwN3qhtxrPq7FFemDJUAXTyZ8</string>
    <string name="project_id" translatable="false">mydemoapp</string>

</resources>
```

You can refer to these links:

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects
2. Processing the JSON file: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#processing_the_json_file.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me realize that my prod application was built with dev params so the validation was giving back error: MismatchSenderID

Answer (score 3):

Actually there are many reasons for this issue.
Mine was because of Invalid token passed.
I was passing same token generated from one app and using same token in another app.
Once token updated , it work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I spent hours on this and finally figured it out. This problem happens if service account your sender application is using differs from the service account your receiver is using.

You can find out your receiver service account via `Firebase -> Project Overview -> Project Settings -> Service Accounts` and generate a new key and use that key when you are initializing your `FirebaseApp` in the sender:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("YOUR_PATH_TO_GENERATED_KEY.json");
GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(googleCredentials).build();
firebaseApp =  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

This initialization need to be done once before you send push notifications.

In my case, I had done everything correctly and I still had this problem. I had made some changes in the "google-services.json" used in the receiver app and I noticed AndroidStudio was not using my new file. The solution was so simple:

`AndroidStudio -> Build -> Clean Project` and Build -> `Rebuild Project`

Answer (score 3):

I got this Error after I added more Product Flavours to my current App,
it seems like it uses the package name to generate the FCM Token, so to reslove the issue I have to add an app for eatch Flavour with it's corresponding PackageName, and update the `google-services.json` file with the latest generated one wich include Client info for each Flavour(Package Name).

Answer (score 2):

For eliminate this error for mismatch sender Id In fcm

`{"multicast_id":7751536172966571167,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}`

there is error occured,

1. So we required first, In FCM, register Application e.g MyDemoApplication
2. After that FCM will generate server key i.e `AIzaSyB9krC8mLHzO_TtECb5qg7NDZPxeG03jHU` and sender Id i.e `346252831806` these format like these.
3. After In Android Studio, our project is connect to these FCM created project i.e MyDemoApplication
4. And most important step is there required to device token or registration id. These token must created in Android Studio..
5. After that using Sender Id and API key in web API project u will be definitely getting notification

Answer (score 1):

check **gcm_sender_id** in manifest.json 
If mismatch - correct, but you need make new subscribers for new sender Id.
Exists subscribers break.

Answer (score 1):

As per response "MismatchSenderId", this is a mismatch between FireBase and your local "google-services.json", you have to make sure that both manifests matches

In FireBase console you go to "YourProject > Project OverView > Cloud Messaging" you'll see the "SenderID" which MUST match with the "google-services.json" in your Android project.

Best thing you can do is download the final json file from "General" tab and place it in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while trying to send push notificaion. Get the updated google-services.json file and replaced with it. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case someone had deleted APN SSL Certificates for my app in Apple development portal.

- I needed to create new certificates: Identifiers / My AppId / Push Notifications / Edit.
- Then I uploaded them to the Firebase project from console: Project Settings / Cloud Messaging / iOS app configuration / APNs Certificates.

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to send notification using the fcm api "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" from postman. Server key was ok and token was pasted fine but was still getting error "MismatchSenderId".

Then introduced the follwoing dependency in the gradle file on android side.

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
```

and it started receiving notifications on the device

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your "package_name" in the google-service.json file is your applicationId from build.gradle(app) file.

```
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "" // -> your applicationId
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for this problem after 5 years of using Firebase.

Of course, this happened to me when I tried to get a new google-services.json file for old projects.

When you receive the new file, you must use the latest version of google-services.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:$.$.$'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check what google-services.json your app is using by logging react native firebase options like this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(messaging().app.options));
```

It will print the messagingSenderId and much more.

For me in react-native project the reason was that I had not cleaned the project after I replaced the google-services.json with a new one.

After running:

```
gradlew clean (in android folder)
```

Notifications started to work.
To make sure I also stopped emulators, wiped data from them and restarted.

In our case the UI send's it's FCM token to backend and the backend send's the notifications when needed.
So the problem was that the FCM token was generated with the incorrect google-services.json and the backend was using the correct new values and there was a mismatch.

I had two errors: NOT SENT - REQUESTED ENTITY NOT FOUND and SenderId mismatch
Was looking for answer also from here:

[Requested entity was not found when trying to send a push notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging in Firebase Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56216887/requested-entity-was-not-found-when-trying-to-send-a-push-notification-using-fir)

"react-native": "0.68.1",

"@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.1.1",

"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.1.1",

Comment: if `gradlew clean` is not working delete the android build folder and build again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it like this:

1. Go to your google fcm console
2. Select your app
3. In the left side menu find settings icon (standard wheel)
4. Click on it and after click on project settings
5. Now copy your server key and paste it in php

Voila...

Answer (score 0):

Updating firebase initialization works for me..

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
 <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I was using the `phonegap-plugin-push` in cordova, testing the app with the phonegap app.

The problem with this is that for some reason with this plugin, the phonegap app intercepts it and returns a dummy registration key, no matter what sender ID you have.

So to make it work (as long as you have all your keys right) is to test your program some other way, with an emulator, or android emulation via usb. And your keys will match.

Hopefully this saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

your probably doing whwat i was doing. GCM token is not the same as FCM anymore. check if your pulling the GCM token ID instead of FCM. just override FirebaseInstanceIdService & ensure your getting the right ID.  i thought at one point they were the same but now there not. i logged a test and saw.  after you do that also update google-services.json like others say as a safety.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that when a device id is created in GCM you cannot send push messages through FCM using the new server key, you have to use the old API-key.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted days on this.

In my case, I followed this [blog](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-a-web-app-with-firebase-528a702e13e1) to use Postman and get the mismatchsenderid error.  Previously, I was getting `messaging/mismatched-credential`, and people reported that their client app used multiple projects.

However, for me, I have one-to-one, a web app and a project.  **BUT**, I host all apps via `ng serve` on default port 4200.  So regardless of what project / app pair I was developing on, I would always get the same token from my client web app using `AngularFireMessaging.requestToken` - this token was always the token created on my first ever run of a firebase app in development.

As a work around, I start different apps / projects on different ports and get proper tokens for respective projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had big trouble figuring out why I was getting a "MismatchSenderId" status.
I added the gms dependency in the root `build.gradle` but my error was actually not applying the gms plugin in the app `build.gradle`.

If you have don't have this line in the app `build.gradle`, this could be the reason why the notification are not working:
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Answer (score 0):

Note: I had truncated the first part of the FCM token (before `:`) and the error was `MismatchSenderId`

Fixed my script and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was very simple. I was pulling the wrong registrationId from the database. After I pulled the correct Id, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we made notifications using Flutter. We decided to separate dev and prod server notifications by creating a second firebase account and configuring them. The problem was that `flutterfire configure` did not modify the existing GoogleService-Info.plist, so all we had to do was download the correct file and replace it with the existing one.

You can find the file via this path Project Overview -> click on iPhone app on the apps panel -> click on appeared "settings" button and below you can see your apps where you should choose Apple apps and click on 'GoogleService-Info.plist' button to download it.

Answer (score -3):

I also getting the same error. i have copied the api_key and change into google_services.json. after that it workig for me

```
"api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "********************"
        }
      ],
```

try this