# MismatchSenderId in push notification with Ruby

Tags: ruby, push-notification, padrino

I am building a backend with Ruby (padrino framework) and would like to send push notification.
I used this gem for push notification.

https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm

I used server key from firebase console could setting.
This is code what I have used.

```
fcm = FCM.new(settings.fcm_serverkey)
registration_ids= [settings.test_key] 
options = {data: {score: "123"}, collapse_key: "updated_score"}
response = fcm.send(registration_ids, options)
```

And this is error what I got.

```
{:body=>"{\"multicast_id\":8815634661444747749,\"success\":0,\"failure\":1,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"error\":\"MismatchSenderId\"}]}", :headers=>{"content-type"=>["application/json; charset=UTF-8"], "date"=>["Wed, 20 Dec 2017 21:05:04 GMT"], "expires"=>["Wed, 20 Dec 2017 21:05:04 GMT"], "cache-control"=>["private, max-age=0"], "x-content-type-options"=>["nosniff"], "x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"], "x-xss-protection"=>["1; mode=block"], "server"=>["GSE"], "alt-svc"=>["hq=\":443\"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"41,39,38,37,35\""], "accept-ranges"=>["none"], "vary"=>["Accept-Encoding"], "connection"=>["close"]}, :status_code=>200, :response=>"success", :canonical_ids=>[], :not_registered_ids=>[]}
```

What the important thing is "MismatchSenderId" from error log.
I can't find param for senderID in github guide.
They only mentioned about serverkey.
Any advice will be big help for me.
Thanks

Comment: You sure you are using right token for right project? [check_out_this_answer](https://codedump.io/share/wdirXzlaIuaY/1/firebase-mismatchsenderid-when-authorization-key-is-my-server-key) And you checked out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863106/fcm-getting-mismatchsenderid)?

Comment: Did you find anything in the last month?

Comment: hi do you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same issue recently.
In my case, I was not using the correct Server-ID because we have to use the Server-Id from the project where our app has been registered.

You can check this in [Google-services.json](http://alphatech.technology/Howto-Entry-srk/Google-Services-Json-bek/)

secondly please ensure that you allowed and added your App to your Firebase project.

I find the best reason explanation [here](https://codedump.io/share/wdirXzlaIuaY/1/firebase-mismatchsenderid-when-authorization-key-is-my-server-key)