# FCM error Mismatchsenderid

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending Push nitifications from PHP using cURl with Firebase Cloud Messaging.
But notificatons sending return MismatchSenderId error with correctly server key (from Firebase -> Project -> Settings -> Cloud messaging tab).

Help me, please)

P.S. Sorry, mistackes from ask - English is not my language.)

P.P.S. I can using Google and do it all night.
I visited Cloud Messaging Tab in project settings, paste Server Key, API Key and Sender ID to the key=AAXXXXX:XXXXXXX place.
All it is doesn't work.
I paste not server key - return 401 error.
I paste server key - return mismatchsenderid error.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FCM getting MismatchSenderId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863106/fcm-getting-mismatchsenderid)

Comment: Writed from mobile, can't paste code at this moment(

Answer (score 0):

I had two keys registered in my account, it started working when I left only one