# "error": "InvalidRegistration" while sending push notifications

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing FCM push notifications using  [**`FirebasePushNotificationPlugin`**](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin) in `Xamarin.Forms`. In iOS project, in `AppDelegate` when `RegisteredForRemoteNotifications` method calling `deviceToken` generating but when I am sending notification for generated `token` by Postman I am getting error.

> { "multicast_id": 8631208504861228784, "success": 0, "failure": 1,
>   "canonical_ids": 0, "results": [ { "error": "InvalidRegistration" } ]
>   }

This is the code I have on `AppDelegate` got from [here](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/samples/FirebasePushSample/FirebasePushSample.iOS/AppDelegate.cs):

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());

    FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, new NotificationUserCategory[]
    {
        new NotificationUserCategory("message",new List<NotificationUserAction> {
            new NotificationUserAction("Reply","Reply",NotificationActionType.Foreground)
        }),
        new NotificationUserCategory("request",new List<NotificationUserAction> {
            new NotificationUserAction("Accept","Accept"),
            new NotificationUserAction("Reject","Reject",NotificationActionType.Destructive)
        })
    });

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}

public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);
    Console.WriteLine("Token- - - :  "+deviceToken);
}

public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
{
    FirebasePushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);
}

public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
    FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
    System.Console.WriteLine(userInfo);
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
}
```

data `object` in Postman when sending sample notification

```
{ 
 "to":"79f64b43339859a329a935f7a3e417ecc1599fbb5d6935afbooa3b4291c07fa7", 
 "notification" : {
 "body" : "New task",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 "color":"Page1",
 "title":"Announcement"
 },
 "data" : {
 "color":"Page1",
 "title":"title",
 "content_available" : true,
 "body" : "New Announcement ad"

}
}
```

Body of Postman

[image]

These are the Provisioning profiles setting from Visual Studio

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: In iOS Speaking, it's a `(NS)Data` object. Usually, we translated it "as such" into a String Hex for our back end (the last combination should be the one to work).

Comment: @Larme - Thank you for your input.

Comment: Did you create everything on FCM properly? You have uploaded push certificates created in Apple Developer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Xamarin. But I worked with FCM a lot.

I think you are getting wrong token. Using `deviceToken` won't work with push notification from FCM. I did a search and maybe you have to get it from

`var fcmToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;`

More detail: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=macos

Comment: @Arvindraja It means the token for `to` client is right. And you're having another issue, maybe your auth is wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863106/fcm-getting-mismatchsenderid

Comment: Last three days I have tried everything but not getting first notificN. Sender Id is same on portal and in GoogleService file.

Comment: @Arvindraja 2
The MismatchSenderId error is encountered when you are attempting to send to a registration token that is associated with a different Sender (Project). Please check your Authorization key (in Postman) and Project ID(where you got fcm token from)

Comment: I have two projects with same bundleID. First is working as usual. When I am downloading new GoogleJson file and adding to 2nd project and getting FCM token while debugging. To that token notification not getting sent. Authorization key is always one which I am using from Firebase portal. I have only one project on firebase.

Comment: @Arvindraja Does token device from 1st project work with Postman (with same Auth key)?

Comment: @Arvindraja Wait... I see your Authorization key in Postman is `Alza.....` It's wrong. Use the key like `AAAA....`. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863106/fcm-getting-mismatchsenderid/42290231#42290231

Comment: @Arvindraja You have to do 2 things: 1. Get fcm token as my answer. 2. Change your Auth key to `AAAA....`. Then Postman will work

Comment: first project is working with Postman with the same keys. But second not working. I checked both keys, Server key and Legacy server key are same it doesn't make any diff. However I tried both but not working for second project. So can u please help me regarding this.

Comment: @Arvindraja So weird. Can you please try to copy Google..json from 1st project to 2nd instead of download new one?.

Comment: I  got it work. I have one more googleJson file added in Resource folder which had different SenderId so I was getting this error. Now working everything.

Comment: @Arvindraja Nice!!!. What did you change? Just changed the googleJson? Did you use `FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token` or just `deviceToken`?

Comment: I have been using `Instance.Token` not `deviceToken`. But due to hidden GoogleJson file, notification was not working. When you answered this question just one day before I came to know about `Instance.Token`. As per question your answer is correct, SenderId issue was additional. Can you have look on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/remote-notifications-in-ios) and search for _DeviceToken_

Answer (score 0):

**Edited because my initial answer regarding RegisteredForRemoteNotifications was wrong**

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/remote-notifications-in-ios), the actual token is in the *Description* of the token received:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (
UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    // Get current device token
    var DeviceToken = deviceToken.Description;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DeviceToken)) {
        DeviceToken = DeviceToken.Trim('<').Trim('>');
    }

    // Get previous device token
    var oldDeviceToken = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("PushDeviceToken");

    // Has the token changed?
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldDeviceToken) || !oldDeviceToken.Equals(DeviceToken))
    {
        //TODO: Put your own logic here to notify your server that the device token has changed/been created!
    }

    // Save new device token
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(DeviceToken, "PushDeviceToken");
}
```

So the token is DeviceToken above.

As an alternative to implementing _ RegisteredForRemoteNotifications_, you can do the following:

1. Make your AppDelegate implement the IMessagingDelegate interface.
2. Implement the following method:

   // This callback is fired whenever a new token is generated - in order for it to be called, the AppDelegate must be an IMessagingDelegate

   [Export("messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:")]

   public async void DidReceiveRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string token)
           {

   ```
           // Subscribe to a 'news' topic so we can send to just those subscribed to this topic
           messaging.Subscribe("news");


           // Log this to debug output so that we can capture it for testing
           Debug.WriteLine($"DidReceiveRegistration Token:'{token}'");


       }
   ```

Comment: Not working this at all. This already I have been following..If you read my question properly.

Comment: Sorry - my code for the DidReceiveRegistrationToken was wrong. I've corrected it. I suggest you try that approach.