# Flutter IOS FCM push notification not coming into notification bar

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am new to Flutter and IOS. I am configuring FCM push notifications for both Android and IOS.For android its working fine.I have done by referring this link https://medium.com/@jun.chenying/flutter-tutorial-part3-push-notification-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-2fbdd84d3a5e
 . For IOS, if the app is opened and if I send FCM from Firebase Console at the same time , Flutter on message is called (See the screenshot , logs are there) . But if I close the app , notification is not coming to notification bar but I am receiving in Android App,
I don't know where is the problem , Problem with Apple Profiles or Flutter .

IOS Build Settings and Signing & Capabilities

[image: IOS build Settings]

Here is my code in flutter,

```
    class FirebaseNotifications {
       FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging;
       SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;

       void setUpFirebase() {
         _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
         initializeSharedPreferences();
         firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners();
        }

        void initializeSharedPreferences() async {
        _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        }

        void firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners() {
        if (Platform.isIOS) iOS_Permission();
        _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
        _sharedPreferences.setString(Preferences.device_token, token);
         print('Token'+token);
         });

         _firebaseMessaging.configure(
          onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print('on message $message');
         },
          onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print('on resume $message');
         },
         onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
         print('on launch $message');
         },
       );
     }

     void iOS_Permission() {
     _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
     IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
     _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
     .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
     print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else runs into this in the future, to expand on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62118164/11198609). The issue was that in the `Info.plist` `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` was set to bool rather than a string so:

```
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    </false>
```

becomes

```
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <string>0</string>
```

Comment: You saved my life ! I add to migrate from classic notification to silent push notification using Notifee. Can't make it works ... Until I disable `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` with string value ... You also have to implement `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and `didReceiveRemoteNotification` to make it works and don't forget the `content-available` inside your `apns` payload !

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I was hitting my head on the roof :)

Answer (score 1):

it's weird that it says Push Notifications (Profile) in your Xcode Capabilities Tab.

Maybe remove it again and add it again. And did you check the boxes "Background fetch" and "Remote notifications" in the "Background Modes"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone in this problem - try [this](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1041#issuecomment-551431409) solution.

Also, check if it not working both on debug and release builds of the application - there is a possibility of notifications not parsed by the debug variant of app.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Please also check [answer]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem with this solution:

1. In your info.plist:

   ```
    FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled: false
   ```
2. Add this to your AppDelegate:

   ```
   override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

      Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
      super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
    }
   ```

Comment: Quote your answer with the [references](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#token-swizzle-disabled) when you're just copying it.

Answer (score 1):

### Make this replacement in your `info.plist` file .

Replace `<false/>` by `<string>0</string>`

**Before :**

[image]

**Now :**

[image]

> **Info :** If you don't have this code in your info.plist and you don't
> receive the notification as well, make sure you add it.

Don't forget , here is the new code :

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<string>0</string>
```

Hope that it will be useful