# FireStore Push Notification Using python

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase database

i want to send push notification to the each fcmtoken that saved.

i want to send the all device,  i am having the unique deviceId and  fcmtoken

i want to write the firestore function for this

i tried this one

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials,messaging
from firebase_admin import firestore

# Use the application default credentials
cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
  'projectId':'project',
})

db = firestore.client()

import json


def hello_firestore(data, context):
    """ Triggered by a change to a Firestore document.
    Args:
        data (dict): The event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
   

    print('\nNew value:')

    newfld = data["value"]["fields"]
    print(json.dumps(newfld))

    newfld1 = newfld["latestMessage"]
    print(json.dumps(newfld1))
    msg = newfld1["mapValue"]["fields"]["message"]["stringValue"]
    print(msg)

    user_id = newfld1["mapValue"]["fields"]["user"]["mapValue"]["fields"]["user_Id"]["stringValue"]
    print(user_id)

    newfld2 = newfld["memberIds"]
    print(json.dumps(newfld2))

    receiverIds = newfld["memberIds"]["arrayValue"]["values"]
    print(json.dumps(receiverIds))

    receiverIdslst = list()
    for data in receiverIds:
        receiverIdslst.append(data["integerValue"])

    user_details = db.collection(u'user_info').get()

    for doc in user_details:
        print(doc)
        data = u'{}'.format(doc.to_dict())
        print(data)
        doc1 = eval(data) 
        print(doc1)
        token = doc1['fcmToken']
        deviceuniqueId=doc1['deviceId']

        message = messaging.Message(
            notification=messaging.Notification(
                title="Push title",
                body="Push body"),
            token=token)

        messaging.send(message)

        print("Success")
```

but showing exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/messaging.py", line 352, in send json=data File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 129, in body resp = self.request(method, url, **kwargs) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 117, in request resp.raise_for_status() File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self) requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/pwe-mobile/messages:send During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v1.py", line 402, in run_background_function _function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v1.py", line 222, in invoke_user_function return call_user_function(request_or_event) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v1.py", line 219, in call_user_function event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context)) File "/user_code/main.py", line 77, in hello_firestore messaging.send(message) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/messaging.py", line 116, in send return _get_messaging_service(app).send(message, dry_run) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/messaging.py", line 355, in send raise self._handle_fcm_error(error) firebase_admin._messaging_utils.UnregisteredError: Requested entity was not found.
```

[image]

How can i send push notification to the fcm token?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Requested entity was not found when trying to send a push notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging in Firebase Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56216887/requested-entity-was-not-found-when-trying-to-send-a-push-notification-using-fir)