# FCM - "messaging/registration-token-not-registered" - but the client is still using the token?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

When sending a multicast message to FCM...

```
        const message = {
            notification: {
                title: messageTitle,
                body: messageBody,
            },
            tokens: tokenArray,
        }

        getMessaging().sendMulticast(message)
```

I'm receiving this error.

> messaging/registration-token-not-registered - Requested entity was not
> found

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56216887/requested-entity-was-not-found-when-trying-to-send-a-push-notification-using-fir), I should then remove the token.

Here's what I'm confused about though. When I run `getToken()` on my client device, it's still showing this same token.

```
getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: "MY_VAPID_KEY"}).then(token => console.log(token))
```

Is there like a registration step that I'm missing? I don't understand why the client is using this as the current token but FCM thinks it's unregistered.

Answer (score 0):

So my solution was I reset the browser cache and notification permissions. My browser then generated a new token which is working.

Kind of strange though is on the first call of getToken() after clearing and refreshing, it sent a request to delete the token after failing a check with `isTokenValid()`, and then the delete itself failed so my token remained registered and is now working. No idea what's going on there.