# Not able to receive FCM push notifications on android with correct google-services.json file

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using the right google-services.json file but unable to receive notifications. It was working fine before. I tried with Postman but it says mismatchSenderID. I checked and verified each and everything is correct but still not receiving Push Notification. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863106/fcm-getting-mismatchsenderid

Comment: Yes but nothing worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced same issue what worked for me is:
 - Delete build folder from app directory
 - Clean project
 - Restart Android Studio
 - Rebuild project
 - Uninstall app from device
 - Run

Hope this will work for you too if everything else is fine because sometimes due to down internet or some other issue project may not build properly. ;)

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Happy to know ;)